# How to nest a composite widget into the main ui.xml file using uiBinder?

Tags: gwt, widget, uibinder

I have a task to add a composite widget into the main ui.xml file, but it's not working for some reason. Here is my widget code:

```
public class MyClass extends Composite {
    @UiTemplate("MyClass .ui.xml")
    interface MyClassUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyClass > {
    }

    private static MyClassUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyClassUiBinder.class);

    @UiField Label label;

    public MyClass() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    } ...
```

Then in my main viewImpl.ui.xml class:
I declare the class package:

```
 ... xmlns:u="urn:com... client.view">
```

and then the widget itself:

```
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="mainPanel" styleName="{style.mainPanel}">
<table align="center">
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <u:MyClass/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I also tried setting up a ui:field declaration in the viewImpl class, but I got an error thrown at compile time:

**ERROR] In @UiField myClass, template field and owner field types don't match: com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element is not assignable to com... client.view.MyClass**

When I took the @UiField declaration out of the viewImpl and the ui.xml it compiled, but the widget wasn't displaying when the page loaded.

I created another composite widget class and tried to duplicate this with just a button widget.

Using firebug I see that the element has been added to the main ui.xml page, but it also is not displaying, so my binding isn't totally complete somehow.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem, GWT was telling me that I didn't do my declaration properly, but the error wasn't as descriptive as I would have liked.

In the main.ui.xml file I used:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
 xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
 xmlns:u="urn:com.abc.client.view">
```

However, the last line should have had the word **import** in it:

```
xmlns:u="urn:import.com.abc.client.view">
```

This is where I found the [answer](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6161).

I hope this helps someone, this cost me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show more UI binder markup around where you are inserting the `MyClass` widget, but if you have your widget inside some raw HTML you need to have all this HTML in an HTMLPanel.